# Does a constrained wave function method exist similar to constrained density functional theory?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry

I am trying to find out if a constrained wave function method exists for running quantum chemistry calculations. I know that constrained DFT exists and can be used to constrain the charge density to certain parts of molecule but I was wondering if a similar method exists for Hartree Fock, if not why not? Are there limitations that prevent similar constraints from being applied to Hartree Fock?

Comment: "if not why not" that is always easy: because nobody bothered to make it